# Firebase push notifications for users with specific firestore fields

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently making a chatroom-like app that works with firestore to connect users to a host's session. I ran into a problem where client devices lose connection / stop listening for firestore changes when locked/backgrounded for too long (to my knowledge it's because the device tries to save power by killing long-living processes). I learned that a workaround would be to send a FCM push notification to devices prior to changing the firestore doc so it'd reawaken the app and have the app listen for the firestore doc change. I'm not sure how to implement push notifications, but I learned that it requires a user specific token (that must be protected). Ignoring the fact that I'm not sure how to implement push notifications (noob-friendly pointers would be appreciated), would uploading the user token to firestore as a field be a viable approach? I'm thinking that I can use my helper function (which gets all non-hosts of a specific session) to also send push notifications to each person.

```
 _vibrateAllDevices() async {
    var lobbies = await lobby
        .where('lobbyCode', isEqualTo: _lobbyCode)
        .where('userRole', isEqualTo: 2)
        .get();
    lobbies.docs.forEach(
      (document) async {
        document.reference.update(<String, dynamic>{'vibrate': true});
      },
    );
  }
```

Each lobby is expected to have anywhere from 2-30 people so looping per person doesn't seem to be that big of an issue. Does this seem like a viable approach or is storing tokens to firestore an unsafe? I should also mention that each lobby is expected to only be opened for a short amount of time (~3 hours max) and all information is deleted right after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase through notification if another subscribe to your own topic make sure that another person subscribes the topic when Firestore field is created. When you trigger notification then automatically receive notification in another person in FirebaseMessages service class in which method onmessagereceive.
There is the same way to trigger a notification in firebase and Firestore because server key always same.
I recommended you to read this documentation:
https://medium.com/mindorks/send-device-to-device-push-notification-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-without-using-external-769476c79ffd

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was thinking about the topic route but I heard that it focuses more on having the message be received than being notified ASAP. I need the notification to be received by all devices (they'll be in the same room typically) within seconds, so the faster the better. Do you know if subscribing to topics is okay for that requirement?